# Intel Iris Xe video drivers in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, samsung

How can I install Intel Iris Xe video adapter drivers in Ubuntu 23.04?

I have a Samsung Galaxy Book3 Pro (NP940XFG).

Now the system says that I have Intel® Graphics (RPL-P). In Additional Drivers software, there are no drivers found by the system.

Comment: There would not be any additional drivers. The i915 Intel driver is standard install. This should show it:  `inxi -G`

Answer (score 3):

On all Ubuntu systems and flavors, Intel drivers are installed automatically during the operating system installation. My system is also equipped with an ***Intel Iris XE Graphics adapter*** and typing `lspci -k` shows the following information regarding the graphics adapter:

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Lenovo TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

You can see that the system itself has installed the **i915 kernel driver** automatically. You don't need to do anything else manually.

Comment: Thank you. Now I got it!